Oauth2 customize login page using angular and keep rest of the authorization flow
I have oauth2 client and oauth2 authorization server when I try to open a protected url of client. (it has a cookie a certain session). then it redirects to clients own path /oauth2/authorization/api-gateway-oidc (also has that same session cookie). and then redirects to authorization servers http://auth-server:9000/oauth2/authorize?... path (there it has a Jsessionid cookie) to get access token. Then the auth server redirects to its custom login page to get credentials from user (there is the same jsessionid cookie as previous). then the login page sends post request with username and password (there is the same jsessionId cookie, also set-cookie to another jsessionid). and after successfully authenticated it redirects to the path http://auth-server:9000/oauth2/authorize?... (with cookie jsessionid same as previous set-cookie jsessionid). then the auth server redirects to clients http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/api-gateway-oidc? path with the first session cookie and a set-cookie session. after that it opens clients protected endpoint with the previous set cookie session.
This works perfectly fine. but I want to customize the login page with angular login page ui, and keep the rest of the authorization and session flow intact
I added exceptionHandling in AuthorizationServerCongiguration's SecurityFilterChain bean. And send the post request with username and password from angular login page ui project. but it does not work.
Do anyone help with this please. I want a real world example of only customizing login page while keeping rest of the authorization session flow.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you are using loginForm in http. Use can ignore their default html login page with this Consumer
 http
        .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .formLogin(form -> form
            .loginPage("/custom-login") // Use the correct URL mapping for your HTML page
        );

